# Anonymous tomcat stopped/killed

Tags: tomcat, process, kill

My tomcat is being stopped by some users, who used "kill" command to terminate the process, not `shutdown.sh`. So, how to prevent and track(log) this. Like, user should not able to terminate the process using `kill` unless he has authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat can be killed only if the rogue user(s) have access to the account Tomcat server is using (or the other user is superuser, but that's a different story).

What you need to do is to fix the problem using sysadmin tools and not Tomcat. Simply don't provide Tomcat user account details to other people.

NOTE: other users can still shut down Tomcat gracefully by sending shutdown command to shutdown port but I presume this is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I'd add that for the security conscious this is a good thing. The most secure way to handle shut down is to run Tomcat under a dedicated user account that has minimal privileges (and certainly not the ability to log in) and disable the shut down port by setting it to -1. Use root to start Tomcat (with an su to the right user) and then only root can shut down Tomcat (gracefully will a kill -15) while Tomcat runs with minimal privileges.

Comment: Thanks @MarkThomas for your input! Just a small comment - starting as root (only for being able to use 80 port) I think is a bit overkill. I normally prefer using `iptables` and redirecting everything from port 80 to 8080 (or whatever the port is).

Comment: You misunderstood my point. Tomcat should *never* be run as root. You have an init.d script (or any other script) that does something along the lines of "/usr/bin/su $TOMCAT_USER $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh". Strictly, any user with suitable sudo privs can execute that but I normally do it as root. That way Tomcat is always running as $TOMCAT_USER and the only way to stop it is with kill and only root (or a user with su privs to $TOMCAT_USER) can stop Tomcat.